# How is the Point Spectrum of a Compact Operator Countable?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I'm working on understanding a proof that if an operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is compact, then show that $\sigma(A) - \{0\} \subseteq \sigma_p(A)$.  If you're not familiar with this notation, $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum and $\sigma_p(A)$ is the point spectrum.  The first part of the proof succinctly demonstrates how the approximate point spectrum $\sigma_{ap}(A) \subseteq \sigma_p(A)$ and now the proof goes on to claim that $\sigma_p(A)$ is countable.  This is the part of the argument I don't understand and would like some clarification.  Here is the argument paraphrased:

> Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \ldots$ be distinct eigenvalues of $A$ with associated eigenvectors $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$ where $f_n \neq 0$.  Let $g_1, g_2, \ldots$ define an orthonormal set of vectors such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, \; g_n \in Span\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$.  Observe that $Ag_n - \lambda_ng_n \in Span\{f_1, \ldots, f_{n-1}\}$ thus we can express $\lambda_n = \langle Ag_n, g_n\rangle$.  Since $A$ is compact we additionally have that $\lambda_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

How on earth is this argument sufficient for proving $\sigma_p(A)$ is countable?  Each step of the argument is easy enough to understand but how does the main result follow?

Comment: If the point spectrum were uncountable, you could find distinct eigenvalues $\mu\neq 0, \lambda_1,\ \lambda_2\dots$ such that $\lambda_n\to\mu,\ n\to\infty$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Can you illustrate how this can happen?  It's not evident to me.

Comment: The following statement is true: let $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ be uncountable. Then there exist $\mu\in X, \mu\neq 0$ and pairwise distinct $\lambda_n\in X,\ n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\lambda_n\to \mu,\ n\to\infty$. Is this unclear?

Comment: The statement is perfectly clear, but it's not clear to me why it is true.  Is it that every uncountable set contains a cluster point?  I'm trying to think of proving this by contradiction: if $X$ contained no cluster point then every $p \in X$ would have a ball $B_{\epsilon_p}(p)$ containing only finitely many points of $X$.  But in this construction we still have uncountably many balls.  In what direction can I take this argument?

Comment: Let $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ be uncountable. Then some interval $[-n,n]$ contains uncountably many points from $X$. Further, we can find some $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $[-n,-1/m]\cup [1/m,n]$ contains uncountably many points. W.l.o.g. let $\mu\in [1/m,n]$ be a cluster point of $X$. Then there exists a sequence $\lambda_n\in X\cap[1/m,n]$ with required properties.

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason we can assume $X$ has a cluster point in $[1/m, n]$ is that if it did not, we could contain each $x \in X \cap [1/m, n]$ in a ball with only finitely many other points of $X$.  We can add to this collection however many balls to cover $[1/m, n]$.  By compactness only finitely many of them cover $[1/m, n]$ hence $X \cap [1/m,n]$ is finite $\Longrightarrow\Longleftarrow$.

Comment: I hope somebody can still answer my question. Why is it true that $\lambda_n = \langle Ag_n,g_n \rangle$ and that $\lambda_n \to 0?$

Comment: @Kurome When/where did you ask that?  Provide citation, or maybe ask your own separate question.